# How to extract/mount Nero images (nrg)

Tags: 12.04, cd-image

I need to extract the content of a Nero .NRG image. What can I use since I do not want to burn it.

Comment: sudo mount -t iso9660 yourfile.nrg /mnt/

Comment: NRG is not an ISO format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can convert it to iso via  [nrg2iso](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/nrg2iso/)

```
sudo apt-get install nrg2iso
nrg2iso source.nrg desitination.iso
```

or you can try [nero for linux](http://www.nero.com/enu/linux4.html)

Comment: At least it helps in extracting afterwards the information. Thanks Aboobacker.

Comment: Just to add. To use it it is easy: nrg2iso IMAGE.nrg IMAGE.iso.

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 12.04 too, but it doesn't work for me. when use this command, says: `It seems that SOURCE.nrg is already an ISO 9660 image‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍` [Aborting conversion] **I'm sure it's .nrg file because i get it from nero in Windows7**

Comment: @Netmoon: try to rename the file to filename.iso and extract it

Comment: Unfortunately nowadays nrg2iso does not work - converted iso image is empty when mounted via mount and makes Virtualbox display and error. Still looking for another solution. Perhaps my NRG images are too new for the tool?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to convert NRG to ISO using `nrg2iso` program. Another solution is to mount NRG using `acetoneiso2`. Both programs are present in repositories.

Comment: I first tried acetoneiso2 but it gave me an error for the nrg file. I used it first because it said that it supported nrg files. In any case I have just converted the nrg to iso. Thanks for the suggestion sindikat.

Answer (score 3):

Furius ISO Mount could mount or burn .nrg Images

It is in the Software Center

Answer (score 3):

I have a number of `nrg` images that I need to either mount in Ubuntu or have mounted by guest machines in Virtualbox.

Current version of `nrg2iso` is 4.4 from 2004 and it was not able to convert these images to `iso` properly - resulting image was either empty or caused Virtualbox to display errors.

After reviewing different options I installed `gCDEmu` - the most acclaimed software for mounting CD images. Now I have image mounted and readable.

Unfortunately Virtualbox is not able to attach guest machine's virtual CD to the virtual one created by CDEmu. Therefore I used Brasero to copy CD to image to create `iso` file. This way I am able to mount the image directly in Virtualbox.

As `iso` format does not have any built-in checks I have also created hash sums of the created file using GtkHash so in future I am sure the file was not changed in any way.

Comment: gCDEmu is brilliant ! And there is even a PPA for Ubuntu. I've used it to open music CD images in NRG format from 15+ years ago. Playing them in Rhythmbox riigt now :D https://cdemu.sourceforge.io/project

Answer (score 1):

if the message is displayed at the command `nrg2iso file.nrg file.iso`:

```
file.nrg is already an ISO 9660 image [ Aborting conversion ]
```

use

```
sudo mount -t iso9660  /mnt
```

worked for me

Comment: For this VERY specific case, it means that your ISO was renamed to NRG because the file is actually an ISO9660, which means, you would logically rename it back to ISO and proceed on using it like a normal ISO file. Now, for an NRG (Which is specific to Nero), it would not be ISO compliant.